# using NSBezierPath how should add circular progress in mac osx

Tags: cocoa, nsbezierpath

please tell me how should I add circular process using NSBezierPath . I know the method appendBezierPathWithArcWithCenter but how it works.
thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
NSBezierPath * path = [NSBezierPath bezierPath];
[path setLineWidth:2];

NSPoint center = { 250,250 };

[path moveToPoint: center];
[path appendBezierPathWithArcWithCenter: center
                                 radius: 64
                             startAngle: 0
                               endAngle: 321];

[[NSColor whiteColor] set];
[path fill];

[[NSColor grayColor] set]; 
[path stroke];
```

Have a look at [cocoadevcentral](http://cocoadevcentral.com/d/intro_to_quartz_two/)